# Why is the write system call printing an incorrect number of characters?

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm trying to implement the `echo` command using different C functions. Implementing it via `printf` was fairly simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while (--argc)
        printf(((argc == 1) ? "%s\n" : "%s "), *++argv);
}
```

This works great:

```
$ ./a.out Bring a towel
Bring a towel
```

However, when I tried to implement it using the `write` system call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while (--argc) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, *++argv, strlen(*argv));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, ((argc == 1) ? "\n" : " "), 1);
    }
}
```

it is printing strings of incorrect lengths:

```
$ ./a.out Bring a towel
Bringa atow t
```

I checked the string lengths returned by `strlen(*argv)` with `printf` and they seem correct. I also tried flushing after every `write` using `fflush(stdout)`. Why is my `write` system call not working correctly?

Comment: My guess? You’re assuming that the increment happens first, then the value is used to get the buffer, and to get its size. That is not how C works, though.

Comment: To add to Blindy's comment, you should never use multiple references to the same variable like this. The compiler does not guarantee the order in which the references will be used, so the second reference may happen before or after the first. So you should change the code to:
```++argv
write(STDOUT_FILENO, *argv, strlen(*argv));
```
thus guaranteeing that the value used is the same in both references.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I've been spending too much time with some other programming languages.  I just assumed the point of the `++variable` syntax was to *always* increment the variable before it was used and that C evaluated arguments left to right.

Comment: *"the point of the ++variable syntax was to always increment the variable before it was used"* That's correct. *"and that C evaluated arguments left to right"* But that's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour as **the order of evaluation of function parameters is not specified**. There is also no sequence point there. Also, operations on the `argv` itself invokes undefined behaviour.

If you rewrite your program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **myargv = argv;
    while (--argc) {
        myargv++;
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, *myargv, strlen(*myargv));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, ((argc == 1) ? "\n" : " "), 1);
    }
}
```

It will work fine

You can see what is going on by modifying your original program.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t len[10];
    while (--argc) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, *++argv, (len[index++] = strlen(*argv)));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, ((argc == 1) ? "\n" : " "), 1);
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu\n", len[i]);
    }
}
```

You will see that the first call to `strlen` is giving you the length of `argv[0]` in your and [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ErE1czEoE) implementation.

Comment: Yes it does [work fine](https://godbolt.org/z/rojcshPb3)

Answer (score 1):

I've added variable `iii` for some precision indexing of `argv`.  Incrementing `argv` simply wasn't having the results you expected.  Other minor mods added using index and argc to attain desired print out.

Runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9bMYKsY4W) for you to see and experiment with, if desired.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int iii=1;
    while (iii < argc) 
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, argv[iii], strlen(argv[iii]));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, ((iii == argc-1) ? "\n" : " "), 1);
        iii++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    Bring a towel
```